# Why switch the lists order when we try to append two lists by using foldr?

Tags: haskell, fold

I see a [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173559/using-foldr-to-append-two-lists-together-haskell) explaining how to append two lists using foldr.

But I don't understand why we have to switch the lists' order.

```
append xs ys = foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys xs
```

The first move would be

```
[y,x] (\x y -> x:y) foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys' xs'
```

Am I correct? Will the result then put ys in front of xs?

Shouldn't it be

```
append xs ys = foldr (\x y -> x:y) xs ys
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first move would be
>
> ```
> [y,x] (\x y -> x:y) foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys' xs'
> ```

That's not a valid Haskell expression, but I think what you mean to express here is that you take one element from each list and then insert them in front somehow. That's not how `foldr` works - it does not iterate over the elements of the `z` argument (`ys` in this case) - in fact that argument doesn't even have to be a list.

Instead `foldr f z (x:xs')` expands like this:

```
x `f` foldr f z xs'
```

and `foldr f z []` expands to `z`.

So in your case, the first step would be:

```
x : foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys xs'
```

This will continue until we get to the empty list, in which case `ys` will be the result. So:

```
  foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys [x1, x2, ..., xn]
= x1 : foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys [x2, ..., xn]
= x1 : x2 : foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys [..., xn]
= ...
= x1 : x2 : ... : xn : foldr (\x y -> x:y) ys []
= x1 : x2 : ... : xn : ys
```

And from this you can see that the elements of `xs` are put in front of `ys`.

Comment: Oh, get it. Thank you. Yea, I'm also looking at the `foldr` document. But I need a more detail example. So is `'f'` the same function as `f`?

Comment: @user8314628 `f` with backticks around it is just applying `f` as an infix operator. I could've just as well written `f x (foldr f z xs')`, but I thought it would be clearer in infix notation because `:` is an infix operator.

Answer (score 2):

The first move wouldn't be that. Check the type of foldr

```
    ghci>:t foldr
    foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Just for simplifying let's assume `t` to be `[]`. In that case, foldr is:

Give me a function `f` which takes an `a` and a `b` and returns a `b`. Give me an initial element and a list of `a`. I will produce a `b`.

So, the way it works is: take the last element of the list and apply f to that element and the initial value producing a `b`. Take the new last value of the list and apply f to that and the previous result... and so on.

In your case, the initial element is actually a list and that's messy. But check this computation. Keep in mind that [1,2,3] is used as initial value, so we don't "loop" over it

```
    foldr (\x y -> x:y) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
    foldr (\x y -> x:y) 6:[1,2,3] [4,5]
    foldr (\x y -> x:y) 5:6:[1,2,3] [4]
    foldr (\x y -> x:y) 4:5:6:[1,2,3] []
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is that `foldr c n list` "replaces" every `:` in `list` with `c` and the final `[]` with `n`.

To append `xs` with `ys`, one needs to "replace" the final `[]` inside `xs` with `ys`. Instead `:` should be replaced with itself.

Hence, we get `foldr (:) ys xs`.